# Can't add 'phone' field in form

Tags: php, html

First of all, I'm using a template on my website.

This template has a contact.php that works fine, is this:

```
<?php 

include 'config.php';

$nombre = stripslashes($_POST['nombre']);
$correo = trim($_POST['correo']);
$asunto = stripslashes($_POST['asunto']);
$mensaje = stripslashes($_POST['mensaje']);

$headers= "De:".$correo."\nPara:".WEBMASTER_EMAIL;

if(mail(WEBMASTER_EMAIL, $asunto, $correo, $mensaje, $headers))
{
   echo "<script>alert('Hemos recibido tu correo, nos pondremos en contacto contigo lo antes posible.'); location.href='http://www.myweb.com/';</script>";
}
else
{
    echo "<script>alert('Error, intentelo de nuevo o más tarde.'); location.href='http://www.myweb.com/';</script>";
}
```

This is the html of the form:

```
<form action="assets/contact/contact.php" method="POST">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <p><input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Nombre" name="nombre" required=""></p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <p><input class="form-control" type="email" placeholder="Correo electrónico" name="correo" required=""></p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <p><input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Asunto" name="asunto" required=""></p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" name="mensaje" required=""></textarea>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <input type="submit" class="btn-white" value="Enviar">
                </div>
            </form>
```

Im trying to add a phone field by this:

HTML:

```
<div class="col-md-12">
                    <p><input class="form-control" type="tel" placeholder="Teléfono" name="telefono" required=""></p>
                </div>
```

contact.php

```
<?php 

$telefono = stripslashes($_POST['telefono']);

$headers= "De:".$correo."\nPara:".WEBMASTER_EMAIL;
```

But doesnt works :(

Comment: Well, do you ever use `$telefono` variable anywhere?

Comment: any error or warning message?

Comment: @Qirel I create the variable $telefono to request the input, like im doing with 'nombre', 'correo', etc. All works fine, but 'telefono' gives me the problem.

Comment: @Znaneswar it gives me de error message from the 'else': "Error, intentelo de nuevo o más tarde."

Comment: @MarkLenders Yes, you might *define* the variable, but I don't see any code that *use* that variable, for instance appending it to the `$mensaje` variable (so its a part of the email-body).

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
$mensaje = stripslashes($_POST['mensaje']);
```

to

```
$telefono = stripslashes($_POST['telefono']);
$mensaje = stripslashes($_POST['mensaje']). PHP_EOL. "telefono" .$telefono;
```

This variable is not added to an email message. Small tip for you, use English for coding.